# C++: Vector of vectors

Tags: c++, stl

I need to create a vector of vectors (Vector of 3 vectors to be precise). Each constituent vector is of different datatype (String, double, user-defined datatype). Is this possible in C++? If not, is there any other elegant way of realizing my requirement?

Comment: What are you going to do with them?

Comment: Sometimes I see someone creating three vectors instead of one vector of structs with three attributes. Is this your case? :)

Answer (score 14):

If you know there's three of them, and you know their types, why not just write a class?

```
class Data
{
    std::vector<std::string> _strings;
    std::vector<double> _doubles;
    std::vector<UserDefined> _userDefined;
public:
    // ...
};
```

This would also give some strong semantics (a vector of unrelated stuff seems weird in my opinion).

Comment: If you don't like to create a class like @Etienne suggests, you can create a `std::vector< boost::tuples<std::string, double, YourType> >`. If you don't have boost (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) installed then `tuples` are supported in recent C++ standard library under `tr1` namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982771.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T> struct inner_vectors {
    std::vector<double> double_vector;
    std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
    std::vector<T> user_vector;
};

std::vector<inner_vectors<some_type>> vector_of_vectors;
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct or a class is in my opnion the best way to go, and is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
vector<tuple<vector<string>, vector<double>, vector<T> > >
```